# Uploading a file with RestSharp returns status-code: 422

Tags: c#, api, restsharp

When I try to upload a file to an API with the help of RestSharp, I get the response:

```
'Error calling UploadFile: {"message":"The given data was invalid.","errors":{"file":["The file field is required."]}}'
```

When I upload the file to the API using their plattform everything works as expected.
Request:

```
curl -X POST "https://{URL}/v1/customer/files/ef02f89c-accf-4ca5-a05a-456cf65242d3" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "file=@dancing-penguins.gif;type=image/gif"
```

Response:

```
Code 200
    
Response body
Download
{
  "id": "ef02f89c-accf-4ca5-a05a-456cf65242d3",
  "fileName": "dancing-penguins.gif"
}
```

My code to upload the file:

```
        private ApiResponse<File> UploadFileWithHttpInfo(File file, byte[] fileData)
        {
            var pathParams = new Dictionary<string, string>() { ["id"] = Configuration.ApiClient.ParameterToString(file.Id) };
            var headerParams = new Dictionary<string, string>(Configuration.DefaultHeader);

            string httpHeaderAccept = "application/json";
            if (httpHeaderAccept != null)
                headerParams.Add("Accept", httpHeaderAccept);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Configuration.AuthString))
                headerParams["Authorization"] = Configuration.AuthString;

            var fileParams = new Dictionary<string, FileParameter> { ["file"] = FileParameter.Create(file.FileName, fileData, file.FileName, MapContentTypeFromExtension(file.FileName)) };
            string path = "/v1/customer/files/{id}";
            Method method = Method.POST;

            var request = new RestRequest(path, method);

            foreach (var param in pathParams) request.AddParameter(param.Key, param.Value, ParameterType.UrlSegment);

            foreach (var param in headerParams) request.AddHeader(param.Key, param.Value);

            foreach (var param in fileParams) request.AddFile(param.Value.Name, param.Value.Writer, param.Value.FileName, param.Value.ContentLength, param.Value.ContentType);

            // set user agent
            //RestClient.UserAgent = Configuration.UserAgent;
            request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
            InterceptRequest(request);
            var response = RestClient.Execute(request);
            InterceptResponse(request, response);

            Exception exception = ExceptionFactory(nameof(UploadFile), response);
            return exception == null ? new ApiResponse<File>(Configuration, response) : throw exception;
        }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I passed the wrong argument to the RestSharps AddFile method. Instead of the tag: 'file', I passed the filename.

```
foreach (var param in fileParams) request.AddFile("file", param.Value.Writer, param.Value.FileName, param.Value.ContentLength, param.Value.ContentType);
```